# Do not raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if nested attributes marked for destruction do not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, accepts-nested-attributes

I'm using [Rails nested attributes](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) with `allow_destroy: true`. If I call something like this:

```rb
deck.update(deck_items_attributes: { id: 1000, _destroy: true })
```

and the `deck_item` with id `1000` does not exist Rails raise the exception `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

Is there any way to tell Rails not to throw the exception and just ignore that record?

Comment: The only way I see is to rewrite method `#update` of your `Deck` model

Comment: @AlexGolubenko I don't see why you deleted your answer. You where 75% there. All thats was missing was a check if the attributes where present.

Comment: @max I have checked it on my local and `reject_if` doesn't run on `update`, maybe I miss something but..

Answer (score 1):

Use the `reject_if:` option to drop the attributes hash if the record does not exist:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :deck_items,
   reject_if: :deck_item_does_not_exist?

private
def deck_item_does_not_exist?(attributes)
  if attributes["id"].present? && attributes["_destroy"].present? 
    DeckItem.where(id: attributes["id"]).none?
  else
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: @Pioz yes it will in fact generate N+1 queries. Which can be avoided if you eager load / include the assocation and check for the existance off it. Its kind of out of scope of the original question though and I avoided it as I know nothing about your assocations. Feel free to ask a seperate follow up question.

Comment: You can also use `!deck_item_ids.include?(attributes["id"])` and Rails should cache the query which fetches all the ids at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use begin rescue to handle such type of exceptions like this

```
begin
  deck.update(deck_items_attributes: { id: 1000, _destroy: true })
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  puts custom_error_msg
end
```

Comment: Yes, but I want that other attributes still saved on DB.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone looking for a solution to the RecordNotFound exception when using nested_attributes, I ended overwriting the method that raises that exception in an initializer as follows:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module NestedAttributes
    def raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found(association_name, record_id)
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Edit: This change is application wide. If you want a per model solution, you can overwrite the same method on your desired model.